# How to separate the modulated signal on a DC supply into signal and power

Tags: audio, decoupling

I a have an AC audio signal modulated on a DC power rail. The AC signal might be around 0.7 V pk-pk, but on the transmission line it can be higher. The DC power supply is 30 V @ 2 A max. With the power supply, I supply 10 units, each drawing 100..200 mA.

Inside each unit, I need a 'clean' power rail and the audio signal.

The audio signal must be good enough to be able to transmit music for listening on cheap headphones. The circuit must not be the part that makes the sound poor quality.

Would a circuit like the following work?

(The point between R2 and R3 is V/2, used as the Audio Ground.)

[image: circuit]

Comment: This is usually done with balanced pair and ground. Your approach will have a huge noise ftom the power supply ( and the fluctuations of dc will couple to signal ). Serach for phantom power eg. microphone

Comment: Well, I only have 3 pins. One is already used for another audio signal which is full duplex (mics and headphone amps capacitively coupled). And I need to power the units over this cable as well. So either I need to send two audio full duplex signals (well, one full duplex, one one-way) over the same line or need to use the remaining power pin. The ah level on the power pin is freely selectable, however. 30v dc is the voltage for the units. The audio signal could go as high as 5v pk-pk if I find the right way to inject it. However, I need quite stable 30v for the device itself, so I need to...

Comment: ...filter the ac part on the power and the dc part on the audio.

Comment: You need to either supply the op amp with negative voltage on the low side, or you need to replace R4 with a voltage divider to bias the signal at VDD/2. Otherwise the bottom half of you waveform will clip.

Comment: Many systems use an inductor and a capacitor in a bias tee ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bias_tee ) to separate signal from power in audio phantom power ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/phantom_power ) applications. You already have the capacitor C2; you might also consider adding an inductor L1 in series with R1 or replacing R1.